# Where Does the PendingIntent in AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo Get Used?

Tags: android, android-alarms

[The constructor to `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo.html#AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo%28long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) takes a `PendingIntent`, described as "an intent that can be used to show or edit details of the alarm clock". Where is this used by the system? I don't see anything in the Android 6.0 UI that would seem to trigger that `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PendingIntent` is returned by `getShowIntent()` in [AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/app/AlarmManager.java#L835-L837):

```
public PendingIntent getShowIntent() {
    return mShowIntent;
}
```

and it's used in the `onClick()` method of [StatusBarHeaderView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/StatusBarHeaderView.java#L522-L524):

```
PendingIntent showIntent = mNextAlarm.getShowIntent();
if (showIntent != null && showIntent.isActivity()) {
    mActivityStarter.startActivity(showIntent.getIntent(), true /* dismissShade */);
}
```

Visually, the thing the user clicks on to invoke the `PendingIntent` is the date/time of the alarm, shown in the following screenshot in grey to the right of the alarm clock icon:

[image: Android 6.0 Notification Shade, Showing Pending Alarm Clock]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the pending intent should start an activity. Now I see why my `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't receive anything at all.

Comment: Is it mandatory to provide ShowIntent? I can see there is a null check in the code.